# using percent instead of px to centre text over image

Tags: html, css

I want my text to overlap my image (only a bit) center left. I am trying things like `top: -50%`, but doesn't work. I won't have control over the height of the image.

I am using both relative positioned because there is a bunch one after the other, and using relative I can control the spacing between them.

css

```
  .article-txt {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    font-size:35px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 0 50px;
   }

   .article-img {
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     margin-top:50px;
     margin-bottom:-50px; /* overlap image */
     z-index:0;
    }
```

html

```
<div id="article-txt"></div>
<div id="article-img"></div>
```

Comment: can you provide live demo so that we can Assist you

Comment: essentially looks wise the answer below is visually correct, but I want to achieve it without using absolute positioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i can understand from your query you want to acheive this

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index:1;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  top:-100px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index:9;
  

 
}


.text {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSt06aInHbKL6NwLIP-Kx90M-QjhLcnxEDe8LaehoDz7zuqBNFBHg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically, But I want it 'overhanging' on the left side of the image. And your using absolute positioning which I mentioned I'd rather not use, since it takes the element out of the flow

Comment: if you provide the proper code i can help more i thought you want the text in center

Comment: @user3550879 run my code snippet now this is what you want to acheive ???

Comment: looks wise it is, but like I said, I want to avoid using absolute positioning

Comment: @user3550879 why you dont want to use absolute positioning it even works fine on responsive views and you even want to use physical image..?? because you can even get that particular result by using image in background

Comment: When I use absolute, It takes the height of the text out of the flow, so the background image dictates the 'space' between elements. But the text could be larger than the text, so it would overlap other background elements. You are using -100px which is what I used. But I was asking if I could use percent, or another way to make sure it's centered since I don't control the image's height

Comment: @user3550879 percentage is not working px and vh is working on it Brother